# Query: Year of Death of Three Mathematicians

Tags: ho.history-overview

I need the year of death of the following mathematicians all of whom are written up in R.C.Archibald's book Mathematical Table Makers.

Carl Burrau, b. 1867, d. ???? - Danish, astronomer and actuary

Herbert Bristol Dwight, b. 1885, d. ???? - American, tables of integrals

Alexander John Thompson, b. 1885, d. ????, British, statistician, BAASMTC

Thanks for any insight.

Cheers, Scott

Comment: The question about Thompson was re-asked and now answered at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/81825/alexander-john-thompson-logarithmetica-britannica

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Burrau died in 1947 ([source](http://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/S0315086085710154))
Dwight died in 1975 ([source](http://ru.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82_%D0%91%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C_%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82))
I could not find info on A.J. Thompson's year of death.

Answer (score 6):

Just a comment on Šiljak's source about Dwight: the footnote (in Russian) says "Год смерти этого автора точно неизвестен и оценен как 1975", i.e. the year of death of Dwight was unknown by the author of that website and "estimated" as 1975.